# How can I limit ethernet speed via hardware?

Tags: networking, ethernet, modem, switch, gigabit-ethernet

Let's say I have a google fiber. Can I have a modem that is connected to a switch that is connected to many routers and have the connection speed *split* randomly between the routers? If so, how and will each router have a different IP address?

**Edit:**
I'm trying to set up a VPS system where certain computers have access to some routers. The computers host virtual machines and each virtual machine has one dedicated IP.

Comment: Google will only provision one public IP unless you purchase more via a business package.  The switch likely can't go between the modem and first router, unless you buy more IPs on a business package.  The connection speed will not be split randomly between routers.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  There is no reason to use "many" routers, except to create confusing connectivity problems.   If you want to shape traffic you may need data center grade routers and switches.

Comment: different IP= DHCP and NAT handle that part.  There is QOS in linux which means you would have load a router with wrt or dd-wrt or some alternative fimware.  The only issue is the random part, QOS requires numbers that you would have to enter and that would not be random

Comment: In your residential agreement with Google, you agreed to _not_ host any servers. You should get the business package, otherwise you may find that Google shuts down your service for violating the contract. Google is serious about this, and has terminated service many times for this.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, your question is unclear - it depends on what you mean by "via hardware".  If you mean "only harware, and not software", then your flexibility is extremely limited - effectively only having the ability to switch between 10, 10, 1000, 10k bits per second and full and half duplex - unless you start deliberately introducing damage to cables.

If you are looking to "rate limit" like an ISP would do, then you can do this on a switch and/or router - routers generally being the cheaper way of doing it - at least in low volumes and where the information all flows through the router.  Anything better then a home user router  - something running DD-WRT or better - will should you to do speed limiting.

You can do rate limiting on an expensive switch as well, but its probably not worth it.

The trick you appear to be missing is that you can have routers connected to routers, and do the rate limiting on the edge routers (ie at/near where they leave your network for the wider Internet) - although the closer to the edge of your network the more traffic they will need to handle.

If money is no issue, speak to a CCNE and buy a Cisco router for your edge.  If money is a concern, and you are looking at doing it yourself, the way I would do it would be to get a lowish spec but reliable Linux computer with at least 2 network cards (4 is better if you want redundancy), and configure this box to do the traffic shaping/limiting.    If I wanted further control I would purchase a managed switch and then run a separate VLAN between each (router which connects to a VM servers) and then connect the switch to the computer over a trunk port - effectively converting a regular PC + managed switch into a many-port managed router with full QoS.

Of-course, another option would be to treat each VM host as a router, and manage traffic on the VM host - this is a software solution, but routing is not actually that resource intensive.